# My android app can't be installed in my device

Tags: java, android

I developed an android app containing tts engine. After all I succeeded in running the app via emulator. But when I tried to install it in real device, I am getting a message like 'Application not installed'. Does anybody knows the problem, please suggest me

Comment: check **allow unknown applications to be installed** in manage applications

Comment: How do you do the installation? Are you using the Eclipse plugin or do you create the .apk and open it by hand?

Comment: I use .apk file from bin folder which comes under the eclipse workspace and copied it into my device; then tried to install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Logcat.  My guess is that the key you used to sign the app you are installing doesn't match the one on your device.  This would happen if you are signing using a debug key for testing, and are trying to install over the app (having the same package name) that was signed with your production key.

Type: `adb logcat` from the command line to discover your exact error.

Comment: Thanks Booger. That was the mistake; I have already used the same package name for multiple applications. I forgot that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I do this all the time.  Glad that helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just run the app in order to test it on an actual device, just make sure all the USB drivers are properly installed, on you device, the Developer Options and USB Debugging are enabled and from Eclipse you can run it by simply clicking the `"play"` button.

If you want to make a final version of the app (appropriate for uploading to Google Play and distribution, follow the guides on [this link on How to sign your apk](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)